# Gradle: How to make Jar during build

Tags: gradle, jar

I'm generating Java classes from WSDL using [wsdl2java gradle plugin](https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java)
. The classes are generated under *src/main/generated* folder.

How do I pack these classes on Jar and save the Jar on specific location as an intermediate step of the build?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly … Here’s a basic `build.gradle` configuration which generates Java files from WSDL in the desired directory, compiles these Java files and adds the compiled classes to the default jar file produced for the Java project – all by simply running `./gradlew jar`:

```
buildscript{
    repositories{
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'no.nils:wsdl2java:0.10'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'no.nils.wsdl2java'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories{
    jcenter()
}

wsdl2java {
    generatedWsdlDir = file('src/main/generated')
    wsdlsToGenerate = [
        ['src/main/resources/yourWsdlFile1.wsdl'],
        ['src/main/resources/yourWsdlFile2.wsdl']
    ]
}
```

The generated jar file resides in `build/libs/yourProjectName.jar` (in your Gradle project directory).